# Opening and Closing Windows Forms

Tags: c++, winforms, window

In my program I open one window using second, and I want to close this second window automatically. I  try to use Close() after SAMPLEWINDOW->ShowDialog() but it does not work. So  how to do that correctly.

Comment: It would help to see your current code base to locate the issue. Can you add some more details?

Answer (score 0):

Would this work?

```
SecondForm_frm newForm = new SecondForm_frm();
this.Hide();
newForm.ShowDialog();
this.Show();
```

Note: This code is written in C#, but C++ code should be similar.

Comment: `SecondForm_frm newForm = new SecondForm_frm();
this->Hide();
newForm.ShowDialog();
this->Show();`
Now its work .Thanks:)

Comment: It is a very bad idea, for a split second the app has no windows that can get the focus.  The dialog window just closed and the main window is still hidden.  This will, randomly, make Windows decide that it needs to find another window to give the focus to.  The window of another app.  Your main window will restore underneath it.  Use the dialog window's FormClosing event to avoid this.

Comment: @HansPassant Does the code sample on the following page describe the behavior you recommend? http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/csharp/code/299495/show-new-form-and-hide-current-form

Comment: No, exact same problem.  The FormClosed event is too late, the window is already gone.  Use FormClosing as I recommended before.

Comment: @HansPassant Would the same (no window with focus) issue apply between `this.Hide();` and `newForm.ShowDialog();`?

Comment: I made my question it's own post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23319971/properly-hiding-owner-form

Answer (score 0):

```
this->Hide();
SAMPLEWINDOW ^ form = gcnew SAMPLEWINDOW;
form->ShowDialog();
```

Will work in c++